# handling null cases in scala play framework

Tags: scala

I have the following POST body examples:

```
{ "Id": "123abxy"}

{ "customUrl": "http://www.whiskey.com","Id": "123abxy"}

{ "size": "88", "customUrl": "http://www.whiskey.com","Id": "123abxy"}
```

And the following endpoint:

```
case class aType(
    customUrl: Option[String],
    Id:Option[String],
    size:Option[String]
  )

@ResponseBody
  def addCompany(
    @RequestBody a: aType,
    @ModelAttribute("action-context") actionContext: ActionContext
  ): DeferredResult[Created] = Action[Created] 
{

    val customUrl =  {
      a.customUrl
    }

    val size  = {
      if (a.size == None) {None}
      else Option(a.size.get.toLong)
    }

    val Id = {
          a.Id
    }

    val handle = register(
      customUrl,
      Id,
      size
    ).run()

  }.runForSpring[Nothing](executors, actionContext)
```

Also:

```
def register(
    customUrl: Option[String],
    Id: Option[String],
    size: Option[Long]
  )
```

Given the above, I would like to know the correct way to handle the case  where `size` and `customUrl` are not passed into the POST Body.

In this case, since `size` can be either a value (`Long`) or `null` and `customUrl` can be either a `String` or `null`, I would assume the proper data type to handle this would be `Option[String]` and `Option[Long]` for `customUrl` and `size`, respectively.

My question is how should I change the `if-else` clauses to handle the aforementioned scenarios for null or `String`/`Long`, so that I can pass valid variables into the `register(..)` function ?

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

If the `register` function receives size and customURL as Options, what's the problem?

I would do something like this:

```
@ResponseBody
  def addCompany(
    @RequestBody a: aType,
    @ModelAttribute("action-context") actionContext: ActionContext
  ): DeferredResult[Created] = Action[Created] 
{
    val handle = register(a.customUrl,a.id,a.size).run()

  }.runForSpring[Nothing](executors, actionContext)
```

If there is a requirement to return `None` if `size` is not defined then:

```
 @ResponseBody
      def addCompany(
        @RequestBody a: aType,
        @ModelAttribute("action-context") actionContext: ActionContext
      ): DeferredResult[Created] = Action[Created] 
    {

        val sizeOpt = a.size

        val handle =sizeOpt.map { size =>
          register(a.customUrl,a.id,Some(size)).run()
        }

      }.runForSpring[Nothing](executors, actionContext)
```

But even better, would be your register function not to expect `Option`s, and deal only with the primitive types. Then you would only need to map the 3 optional values (I recommend to use for comprehension):

```
for {
  size <- a.size
  url <- a.customUrl
  id <- a.id
} yield register(url, id, size).run()
```

with register defined as:

```
def register(
    customUrl:String,
    Id: String,
    size: Long
  )
```